# Finding initial conditions where solutions of $y^{(5)}+y''=\cos t$ are bounded/unbounded.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Problem is from a past QR exam:

> (1) Find the general solution to
> $$ y^{(5)}(t) + y''(t) = \cos t.$$
> (2) Find an initial condition for which the solution to (1) remains bounded as $t \to +\infty$.
> (3) Find an initial condition for which the solution to (1) remains unbounded as $t \to +\infty$.
> (4) Find a function with the following property: If the function is entered in place of $\cos t$ on the right hand side of part (1), the solution $y \to -\infty$ as $t \to +\infty$ for *all initial conditions*.

The general solution I've found is

$$y(t) = C_1 + C_2 t + C_3 e^{-t} + C_4 e^{t/2}\cos(\sqrt{3}t/2) + C_5 e^{t/2}\sin(\sqrt{3}t/2) - \frac{1}{2} \cos t + \frac{1}{2} \sin t.$$

My question: Is there an easier way to answer (2) and (3) without differentiating this beast 4 times and picking conditions that make the proper coefficients vanish ($C_2 = C_4 = C_5 = 0$ for (1) and $C_3 = 0$ for (2))? For (4), I'm not sure how to proceed. My guess is that you want the inhomogeneous term to be in the span of the terms going that go to 0 as $t \to \infty$, which in this case is $e^{-t}$. But not sure how you ensure that $y \to -\infty$ for all conditions.

Comment: Since it asks for *an* initial condition, for (2) and (3) you can just choose values of the parameters ahead of time and then differentiate them to get initial conditions. That's not too complicated because, as you observe, you can make a lot of them $0$. For instance, just $C_2$ nonzero (rest zero) gives you (2) and all of them zero gives you (3).

Comment: Ah, I'm overthinking this. There was a previous question on these tests where they wanted you to find all the initial conditions so that it remains bounded and guess I still had that lingering in my head. This is def the quick solution.

Comment: @TokenToucan How comes all of them zero gives 3 ? Maybe you meant all of them non zero ?

Comment: @Aryadeva I listed the two backwards. All zero is bounded, just $C_2$ nonzero is unbounded.

Comment: @TokenToucan Thank you for the precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differentiation would be much easier if you use the complex number representation instead:
$$y(t) = C_1 + C_2 t + C_3 e^{-t} + C_4 e^{t\frac{2\pi i}3} + C_5 e^{t\frac{4\pi i}3} - \frac{1}{2} \cos t + \frac{1}{2} \sin t$$
The $C_4$ and $C_5$ coefficients **are complex**.
For the last part, you would need to add a term that diverges to $-\infty$ as $t\to\infty$, so something like $-e^t$ in the particular solution. Taking the derivative two and 5 times, you will get the same thing, so your function will be $$f(t)=-2e^t$$
Notice that there is no term with $e^t$ in the general solution of the homogeneous equation, so you cannot cancel this term. And it diverges faster that any term in the homogeneous solution.

Comment: So, true. I'm so used to approaching these problems so rotely that I didn't think to keep those terms in complex form. That simplifies everything. And to (4), yes, makes total sense. You're basically doing undetermined coefficients method backwards, so to speak. I hate overthinking these problems. Thank you, sir.